# Sequential execution / queue of endpoint of createApi

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

One of my endpoints should be called one by one, since the backend doesnt support multiple parallel requests. Ive tried two ways to do it:

- Using `onQueryStarted`:

```js
const sequenceMutex = new Mutex()

async onQueryStarted(id, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
  // wait until the sequenceMutex is available
  await sequenceMutex.waitForUnlock()
  const releaseSequence = await sequenceMutex.acquire()
  await queryFulfilled // the endpoint already started here, cant manage the execution 
  releaseSequence()
}
```

- Using a different `baseQuery`. But I dont see any way to use a different `baseQuery` for an especific endpoint:

```js
const sequenceMutex = new Mutex()

export const sequentialBaseQueryWithReauth = async (
  args,
  api,
  extraOptions
) => {
  // wait until the sequenceMutex is available
  await sequenceMutex.waitForUnlock()
  const releaseSequence = await sequenceMutex.acquire()
  const result = await baseQueryWithAuthentication(args, api, extraOptions)
  releaseSequence()
  return result
}
```

Comment: take a look at queryFn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate on your answer and kick that `yourEndpointSequentialBaseQuery`.

```js
const apiSlice = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    yourEndpoint: builder.query({
      queryFn: (args, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        await mutex.waitForUnlock()
        const releaseSequence = await mutex.acquire()
        try {
          return baseQuery({
            url: '/your-route',
            method: 'POST',
            body: args,
          })
        } finally {
          releaseSequence()
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```

Comment: I designed my solution to be able to reuse the same code for multiple endpoints (and each one blocking itself). But this solution is clear and a good example for people with the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot access `baseQuery` at `api`, is it actually possible to get it through the api variable?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's the fourth argument#

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created a generic seuqnetial `baseQuery` function to reuse it across the app.

First, create a `baseQuery` that accepts a `mutex` instance as argument:

```js
export const sequentialBaseQueryFactory = (mutex: InstanceType<typeof Mutex>) => {
  const sequentialBaseQuery: BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError> = async (
    args,
    api,
    extraOptions,
  ) => {
    await mutex.waitForUnlock()
    const releaseSequence = await mutex.acquire()
    const result = await yourBaseQuery(args, api, extraOptions) // use your createApi baseQuery
    releaseSequence()
    return result
  }
  return sequentialBaseQuery
}
```

Then, create the custom `baseQuery` for your endpoint using a `mutex` instance :

```js
import { Mutex } from 'async-mutex'

// mutex for sequential calls of your endpoint
const yourEndpointSequenceMutex = new Mutex()
const yourEndpointSequentialBaseQuery = sequentialBaseQueryFactory(yourEndpointSequenceMutex)
```

Use the custom `baseQuery` in your endoint:

```js
const apiSlice = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    yourEndpoint: builder.query({
      queryFn: (args, api, extraOptions) => {
        return yourEndpointSequentialBaseQuery({
          url: '/your-route',
          method: 'POST',
          body: args,
        }, api, extraOptions)
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```